# Get Coordinates LongLat from my website's Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps Javascript API in my website. I want current longlat when i drag map or zoom to any location. Eg. "It does happens on maps.google.com when we drag it shows longlat in URL."

Generally API gives us a KEY and simple initialization code.

```
    function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });

  }
```

But i want current coordinates while moving that map in a variable from my websites Google Map

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
      var lat1 = 37.41463623043073;
      var lat2 = 37.46915383933881;
      var lng1 = -122.1848153442383;
      var lng2 = -122.09898465576174;  

      var rectangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
         paths : [
           new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng1),
           new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng1),
           new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2),
           new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng2)
         ],
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        fillOpacity : 0,
        map : map
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', function(args) {  
         console.log('latlng', args.latLng);
      });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmhku4dh/)

Comment: Hi mayank, Thanks for reply , But its showing blank object in console.. ' latlng > .C"

Comment: Check the console in jsfiddle